# 'name' is unavailable: not available on iOS - XCode11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode11

After upgrading from XCode 10.0 to 11

I am getting the error *'name' is unavailable: not available on iOS*

This is during Build for **Swift 4.2** on XCode 11.0 and 11.1 , I can still build using XCode 10

This is happening in the code of one of the **Objective C** external libraries we have been using through Cocopods.

```
return [(NSNumber *)[table[state] objectForKey:[rule name]] unsignedIntegerValue];
```

I can work around the issue by renaming the variable **name** to **ruleName** , but I would rather not do this.

Why is Xcode objecting to a variable name of name? Is this an Xcode but or is it something I can fix in the build settings

### Edit

The specific pod is **NUI 0.5.5**

In module NUIPShiftReduceGotoTable.m

```
- (NSUInteger)gotoForState:(NSUInteger)state rule:(NUIPRule *)rule
{
    return [(NSNumber *)[table[state] objectForKey:[rule name]] unsignedIntegerValue];
}
```

Comment: *Which* Cocopod is causing the issue?

Comment: OK and whereabouts?  You seem to be making this difficult for some reason.

Comment: I will edit the question and provide more info. I thought I had provided relevant info. It just seems to dislike having avariabled named name, not the pod fault

Comment: That appears to be part of [NUITheme](https://github.com/tombenner/NUIParse), not [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui)?

Comment: It is NUI 0.5.5 which includeds NUIParse

Comment: I guess they bundle multiple repos into a single CocoaPod for some reason.  Weird.  Anyway `[rule name]` is fine, by looking at the repo on github, so I don't know what the compiler is whining about.  You probably need to ask the author for help.

Comment: As mentioned above refactoring the variable name to ruleName works

Comment: I don't see how from the code I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple made a change that can break previously compiling code in Xcode 11.0/11.1. Previously the compiler would be fine with passing the 'name' message to an object that it didn't know the type of. This can happen for many reasons in the weakly typed Objective-C world.

Currently in Xcode 11.1 you can do.

```
id x = nil;
[x name];
```

And this will compile, no problem. But:

```
NSObject *x = nil
[x name];
```

won't compile due to the compiler identifying the most likely selector being the API_UNAVAILABLE one in NSLayoutAnchor.h (maybe).

If the compiler had more information it can map the correct selector. This might be as simple as including the header for whatever has name property in the .m file that is failing.

My guess is something like in NUIPShiftReduceGotoTable.m you add a line
#import"NUIPRule.h"